# Why is DateTime:diff() off by one minute?

Tags: php, datetime

I am using the DateTime::diff() function to echo out how many minutes are remaining as soon as there is a 10 minute difference. But for some reason the minute difference is off by one.

For example if I want to get the difference between the 11:20 and 11:30 it will show 9 minutes left instead of 10.

Also this is only true when using the "now". If i implicitly enter "11:20" in the

```
  $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

Then it will show a 10 minute difference.

Here is an example of the code I have written..

```
$closing_time = "11:30:00";


$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
$time_now =  $date->format("H:i:s");
echo $time_now. "<br>";


$time_remaining = $date->diff(new DateTime($closing_time,new DateTimeZone("America/New_York") ));

$minutes = $time_remaining->i;
```

Comment: check the seconds...

Comment: When calculating the time by minute, you are rounding down the number of seconds in the current minute.

Comment: @Flosculus Thanks for the response. I see now why this is happening. I have tried using `ceil($minutes)` and it still didn't make a difference ... any other way I can round up?

Comment: @json2020 If the minutes are not a float value what are you expecting `ceil()` to do to them?

Comment: This will solve your current problem: `$minutes = $time_remaining->i + 1;`.

Comment: @Alternatex I didn't know that ceil() only works on floats..

Comment: @Flosculus Yhea I already though of that... I was just wondering if there was an actual function I can use to round it up... But I guess I will just use the + 1 . Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If `ceil` rounded integers to the next `10` I would use another programming language.

Comment: @Flosculus Don't be ridiculous, obviously  `ceil` should work on increments of `60`!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the very first comment, check the [seconds](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$time_remaining->s;
```

Then depending on your rounding preference, take it into account (e.g.: `>=30`?).